# How can I delete a video from a Youtube Playlist by its playlist ID?

Tags: c#, api, video, youtube-api

```
var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
});
var newPlaylist = new Playlist();

newPlaylist.Id = "PLQQ-7Yr6sumTIG34_J1QmDIQkAoQZGBF4";


var newPlaylistItem = new PlaylistItem();
newPlaylistItem.Snippet = new PlaylistItemSnippet();
newPlaylistItem.Snippet.PlaylistId = newPlaylist.Id;
newPlaylistItem.Snippet.ResourceId = new ResourceId();
newPlaylistItem.Snippet.ResourceId.Kind = "youtube#video";
newPlaylistItem.Snippet.ResourceId.VideoId = "33v7dvN84Ms";
newPlaylistItem = await youtubeService.PlaylistItems.Insert(newPlaylistItem, "snippet").ExecuteAsync();
```

I can add a video to this playlist with the code above. But I can't delete the video from this playlist.

How can I delete a video from the playlist?

Comment: There is [`PlaylistItems.Delete`](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlistItems.delete) method that deletes item by it's ID you can obtain by, lets say, filtering result from [`PlaylistItems.List`](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlistItems.list) request first.

Comment: it doesnt work :/

Comment: I'm afrad that unless you post the code of your failed attempt we won't be able to tell what's wrong.

Comment: PlaylistItemsResource.DeleteRequest deleteRequest = youtubeService.PlaylistItems.Delete("eCGcC9k7tvw");
            string result = await deleteRequest.ExecuteAsync();// i cant delete video :/ THIS IS MY DELETED CODE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should find inner ID of the video item on a selected playlist like so:

```
private static void RemoveVideo(YouTubeService youTubeService, string playlistId, string videoId)
{
    // Find the matching video item
    var videos = youTubeService.PlaylistItems.List("snippet");
    videos.PlaylistId = playlistId;

    var video = videos.Execute().Items.Where(a => a.Snippet.ResourceId.VideoId == videoId).SingleOrDefault();

    if (video == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Video not found!", nameof(videoId));
    }

    // Now delete it by it's inner ID
    var playlistInsertRequest = youTubeService.PlaylistItems.Delete(video.Id);
    playlistInsertRequest.Execute();
}
```